# Creating an Initial tutorial for game inside my app

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-animation

I have several `iOS` puzzle apps, written with `Objective-C` using `QuartzCore`.
I would like to include a quick `animation` showing how to solve the puzzle. Non interactive is OK.
What would be a small format to use? `Gif-anim`? I would like to use minimal coding (pretty much just a 'do not show again' `UIButton`) and have the entire thing done with graphics file/s. Anyone has any suggestions? Maybe using `web-kit`?
Thanks!!

Comment: What do you mean by "small format"? Lines of Code? Weight of your .app package? Loading Time?

Comment: Mahal, I am looking for something that will go fastest from a set of PNGs or GIFs, each with a single step of the tutorial, to my app.
I could, of course, program the entire thing with user interaction, etc. but rather not spend the resources.
So by small I mean not a byte-heavy video, and something I scan stick in a view...

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing is following the suggestion of Mahal.
I created a view with a simple background image, and four buttons: **Back**, **Close**, **Next slide** and **Previous slide**.
At the start, you can choose to see tutorial. Otherwise, it's available from the help screen.
Sharing flowchart below...

[image: Flow chart and assets description]

Answer (score 0):

What about a UIImageView and an array of PNGs?

```
UIImageView 
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSArray *animationImages
@property(nonatomic) NSTimeInterval animationDuration
```